# Android list view with simplecursor adapter crashes application (No ANR shown)

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a weird problem with listview, while using simplecursor adapter. Here is the error

```
08-31 21:50:14.540: INFO/dalvikvm(12195): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer (will be discarded):
08-31 21:50:14.540: INFO/dalvikvm(12195): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
08-31 21:50:14.540: INFO/dalvikvm(12195):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
08-31 21:50:14.540: INFO/dalvikvm(12195):     at android.database.BulkCursorProxy.close(BulkCursorNative.java:289)
08-31 21:50:14.540: INFO/dalvikvm(12195):     at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.close(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:141)
08-31 21:50:14.540: INFO/dalvikvm(12195):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:43)
08-31 21:50:14.540: INFO/dalvikvm(12195):     at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.close(ContentResolver.java:1575)
08-31 21:50:14.540: INFO/dalvikvm(12195):     at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.finalize(ContentResolver.java:1586)
08-31 21:50:14.540: INFO/dalvikvm(12195):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I have runQueryOnBackgroundThread implemented in my cursorAdapter, which is invoked by the Filter.filter method call from the activity. So I dont have any reference of the cursor in my activity. Everytime I query I understand I get cursor changed callback in my cursor adapter, which extends SimpleCursorAdapter

Here is how it looks

```
public void changeCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Cursor changed ... **************** "+ cursor);
        if (cursor != null) {
            setLoading(false);
        }
        super.changeCursor(cursor);
        initSectionHeaders(cursor);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

`runQueryOnBackgroundThread()` just returns a cursor from a query.

Am I missing something, should the cursor be closed or managed anywhere? Any help on the leads would greatly help. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**** Snippets of my adapter

```
public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
        Log.d(TAG, "runQueryOnBackgroundThread "+ constraint);
        if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null) {
            return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
        }
        return doQuery(constraint, People.CONTENT_URI);
    }

private Cursor doQuery(CharSequence constraint, Uri queryUri){
        StringBuilder selectionStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String selectionArgs[] = null;
        String selection = null;

        if(constraint!=null){
            //ADDING GLOB so that the sql query can interpret linux style wildcards
            selectionStrBuilder.append("(UPPER(").append(People.DISPLAY_NAME).append(") GLOB ?)");

            selection = selectionStrBuilder.toString();
            String constraintStr = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

            //prepend and append '*' - TODO improve
            constraintStr = "*"+ constraintStr;
            constraintStr +="*";

            selectionArgs = new String[]{constraintStr};
        }
        ContentResolver contentRes = context.getContentResolver();
        return contentRes.query(queryUri, null, selection, selectionArgs, People.DISPLAY_NAME);
    }
```

Other than these two functions I have changeCursor overridden as posted earlier and use the cursor in bind view to get the data. I don't close or modify cursor properties anywhere else.

My provider getQuery function looks like

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, orderBy);

        // Tell the cursor what uri to watch,
        // so it knows when its source data changes
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return c;
```

**UPDATE2***

When I run the same program on the emulator I get this stack trace, which is very different from what I see on the tablet.

```
01-03 17:21:44.130: ERROR/IMemory(9328): binder=0x3891a0 transaction failed fd=-2147483647, size=0, err=-2147483646 (Unknown error: 2147483646)
01-03 17:21:44.130: ERROR/IMemory(9328): cannot dup fd=-2147483647, size=0, err=-2147483646 (Bad file number)
01-03 17:21:44.130: ERROR/IMemory(9328): cannot map BpMemoryHeap (binder=0x3891a0), size=0, fd=-1 (Bad file number)
01-03 17:21:44.130: WARN/dalvikvm(9328): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception raised
01-03 17:21:44.130: WARN/dalvikvm(9328):              in Ldalvik/system/NativeStart;.run ()V (CallStaticVoidMethodV)
01-03 17:21:44.130: WARN/dalvikvm(9328): Pending exception is:
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328): Ljava/lang/RuntimeException;: No memory in memObj
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328):     at android.database.CursorWindow.native_init(Native Method)
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328):     at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:518)
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328):     at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:27)
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328):     at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:493)
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328):     at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:491)
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:103)
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:320)
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328): "Binder Thread #3" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x405de828 self=0x8e288
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328):   | sysTid=9336 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:24] handle=959480
01-03 17:21:44.130: INFO/dalvikvm(9328):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
01-03 17:21:44.130: ERROR/dalvikvm(9328): VM aborting
```

And Crashes the application.

I found a bug report on this issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10614)

Anyone faced the same problem? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Just a reminder. This is not an ANR, but an application crash

Comment: Updated** with adapter code snippets

Comment: I don't this there is any problem with how the provider reads the data from sqlite. I replaced provider to return MatrixCursor instead, I still see the same problem.

Comment: any progress on the solution?

Comment: NO :( Not yet. Did you find any soln to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah finally found a soln to this freaking issue. Just that some cursor in some other part of the framework was open. Works when closed.

Comment: Do you mean the cursor open by framework? Or opened by your self?
I am facing the same problem. I used startManagingCursor to close cursor. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: This was because of a cursor I had opened was not closed.