# Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer in android app

Tags: java, android, listview, exception

Good day. I try to create an activity with map view and list view. What I have done

```
public class EnrouteActivity extends MapActivity {

    private ListView pointsListView;

    @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.enroute_work_layout);
         this.pointsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewPoints);

         String[] items = new String[] {"Пункт А", "Пункт Б", "Пункт В"};
         //String[] items = this.GetAdapter();
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
         this.pointsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
         this.pointsListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
         this.pointsListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

     }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    private String[] GetAdapter(){

        Routes routes = new Routes();
        String[] items = new String[routes.points.size()];
        for(int i = 0; i<routes.points.size(); i++){
            items[i] = routes.points.get(i).name;
        }
        return items;


    }
```

part of this layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.81"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"

        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="234dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Список точек по маршруту"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewPoints"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="604dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:apiKey="0FLRiHvfPXL2mqzQihPemczCJMUjk3TTD8umAPw"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and here is exception

```
09-14 13:39:02.331: E/MapActivity(9606): Couldn't get connection factory client
09-14 13:39:02.464: D/dalvikvm(9606): GC_CONCURRENT freed 783K, 6% free 15328K/16199K, paused 2ms+3ms
09-14 13:39:02.464: E/System(9606): Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
09-14 13:39:02.464: E/System(9606): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized!
09-14 13:39:02.464: E/System(9606):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
09-14 13:39:02.464: E/System(9606):     at android.database.BulkCursorProxy.close(BulkCursorNative.java:288)
09-14 13:39:02.464: E/System(9606):     at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.close(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:133)
09-14 13:39:02.464: E/System(9606):     at android.database.CursorWrapper.close(CursorWrapper.java:49)
09-14 13:39:02.464: E/System(9606):     at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.close(ContentResolver.java:1591)
09-14 13:39:02.464: E/System(9606):     at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.finalize(ContentResolver.java:1604)
09-14 13:39:02.464: E/System(9606):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:182)
09-14 13:39:02.464: E/System(9606):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:168)
09-14 13:39:02.464: E/System(9606):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265793/android-list-view-with-simplecursor-adapter-crashes-application-no-anr-shown) topic, but i haven't understand, about what coursor they speak =((

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265793/android-list-view-with-simplecursor-adapter-crashes-application-no-anr-shown

Answer (score 1):

```
09-14 13:39:02.464: E/System(9606): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Binder has been finalized
android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.close(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:133)
```

It seems your cursor adaptor closed before submitting to listview. Review the code carefully for any `close()` calls.

Comment: there no close() operator anywhere. May be there is a solution to open it from code? And what this coursor mean? What is it?

Answer (score 1):

```
      Make sure that you are using proper "MD5 Fingerprint" of your current system   
      where you are developing app. Have look at below link,

      https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey
```